Add a marker on table line
Is there a way to place a visual marker on a line of a table like on the picture below? I have some huge tables with lots of data and between different groups of data I increased the spacing between the rows. To highlight the spacing I want to place a dot.
Yes I could just use a hline, but for aesthetic reasons I prefer some marker like the dot...

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption.}\label{tab:someLabel}
    \begin{tabular}{r|p{0.45\textwidth}}    
      Text text text:&  Numbers\\
      Text text:&       Numbers numbers number number numbers number number\\
      Texxxt:&          Some number\\[2mm]
      % spaced row
      Text text text:&  Number\\
      Text text:&       Number number number
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}


With the nicematrix package, it would be easy to use tikz to add the markers

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption.}\label{tab:someLabel}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{r|p{0.45\textwidth}}    
      Text text text:&  Numbers\\
      Text text:&       Numbers numbers number number numbers number number\\
      Texxxt:&          Some number\\[2mm]
      % spaced row
      Text text text:&  Number\\
      Text text:&       Number number number
    \CodeAfter
      \tikz \fill [red] (4-|2) circle (1mm) ; 
    \end{NiceTabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}

As usual with nicematrix, you need several compilations.


Thank you very much for your answer! With \tikz \fill [red] (4-|2)+(0,1mm) circle (1mm); the circle also ends up in the middle of the line spacing. yshift=1mm, on the other hand, does not seem to work.

Alternatively to F. Pantigny's answer, you can achieve the same effect with a built-in picture environment if for some reason you have not an access to nicematrix or other packages it utilises, e.g. pgfcore. A red colour would still need the xcolor package, though.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\sbox0{%
    \begin{tabular}{r|p{0.45\textwidth}}    
        Text text text:&  Numbers\\
        Text text:&       Numbers numbers number number numbers number number\\
        Texxxt:&          Some number\\[2mm]
        % spaced row
        Text text text:&  Number\\
        Text text:&       Number number number
    \end{tabular}}
    
XXX

\begin{table}[htb]
    \setlength\unitlength{1pt}%
    \caption{Some caption.}\label{tab:someLabel}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(\wd0, \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0)
        \makebox(0,0)[lb]{\usebox0}
        \put(82.4,29){\color{Red}\circle*{6}}% <--- red dot
    \end{picture}
\end{table}

XXX
\end{document}



Thanks for your answer, as long as there is no strange interaction between nicematrix and other libraries I will probably use the other solution for now, but it is very good to know another possibility.

You should use nicematrix if it's working. It's a very handy and useful package. Besides, code is a lot cleaner.  Just beware, you may need several compilations to achieve the final effect (as stated in documentation.)

It is possible with the tabularray package, although it does not provide an interface to position things at the intersections of the borders (alias corners of cells), but with the use of the tikzmark package one could improvise as follows (the use of hooks is needed, because the tabularray package draws borders late, and we want the mark to be before the borders):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mydot}{}{%
    \makebox(0pt,0pt)[lt]{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftsep-0.5\rulewidth}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\belowsep-0.5\rulewidth}{\tikzmark{dot}}}%
    \AddToHookNext{env/tblr/after}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \fill[red] (pic cs:dot) circle[radius=1mm];
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={r|p{0.45\textwidth}},
}
      Text text text: &  Numbers\\
      Text text: &       Numbers numbers number number numbers number number \\
      Texxxt: &          \mydot Some number \\[2mm]
      % spaced row
      Text text text: &  Number \\
      Text text: &       Number number number
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



In the above example, the dot does not sit on the intersection of the borders (i.e. the corner) actually, but with the help of \l__tblr_strut_dp_dim (actually, it is marked internal, so we should not use it, but sadly there is no other token variable we could make use of) it is possible to place the dot exactly.
Also, if you need multiple dots, you need to give them unique names:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mydot}{ O{} }{
    \makebox(0pt,0pt)[lt]{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftsep-0.5\rulewidth}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\l__tblr_strut_dp_dim-\belowsep-0.5\rulewidth}{\tikzmark{dot#1}}}
    \AddToHookNext{env/tblr/after}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember ~ picture, overlay]
            \fill[red] (pic ~ cs \c_colon_str dot#1) circle[radius=1mm];
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={r|p{0.45\textwidth}},
    hlines,
}
      Text text text: &  \mydot[1]Numbers\\
      Text text: &       Numbers numbers number number numbers number number \\
      Texxxt: &          \mydot[2]Some number \\[2mm]
      % spaced row
      Text text text: &  Number \\
      Text text: &       Number number number
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


Note that you should not put a space after the closing square bracket as this space will otherwise show in the relevant cell.

Finally, if you want to use the lower left corner of a cell as anchor and shift the mark along the "axes", you could add a shift to the coordinate:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mydot}{ D(){0,0} O{} }{
    \makebox(0pt,0pt)[lt]{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftsep-0.5\rulewidth}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\l__tblr_strut_dp_dim-\belowsep-0.5\rulewidth}{\tikzmark{dot#2}}}
    \AddToHookNext{env/tblr/after}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember ~ picture, overlay]
            \fill[red] ([shift={(#1)}]pic ~ cs \c_colon_str dot#2) circle[radius=1mm];
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={r|p{0.45\textwidth}},
    hlines,
}
      Text text text: &  \mydot(1,0)[1]Numbers\\
      Text text: &       Numbers numbers number number numbers number number \\
      Texxxt: &          \mydot[2]Some number \\[2mm]
      % spaced row
      Text text text: &  Number \\
      Text text: &       Number number number
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



A first approach to make this an extension to the tabularray package using a library:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewTblrLibrary { tikzmark }
  {
    \UseTblrLibrary { hook }
    \RequirePackage { tikz }
    \usetikzlibrary { tikzmark }
    \AddToHook { tabularray/cell/before } {
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 
          \tikzmark{cell-\arabic{colnum}-\arabic{rownum}} 
        }
        \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_box 
            { 0.5\rulewidth }
            { 0.5\rulewidth }
            { -0.5\rulewidth }
            { -0.5\rulewidth }
        \box_move_down:nn { \dim_eval:n { \l__tblr_row_dp_dim } }
            { \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box }
    }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\UseTblrLibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines, 
    colspec={ l l l }
}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 
\end{tblr}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[red] (pic cs:cell-3-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw[blue] (pic cs:cell-1-1) -| (pic cs:cell-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Amazing - You actually managed to crack the code (pun intended) and provide a solution using tabularray, well done! The only potential limitation I see is that it seems to be necessary to create a new command if you intend to place multiple markers. Would it be possible to define the macro such that it could be used in different places in the same table? I'm also curious if it could be applied to horizontal lines to allow complete customization?

@Atex See my edit. Is this something you can work with?

This will more than suffice - Thank you!
